Error: SAP DBTech JDBC: [2048]: column store error: search table error: [34023] Instantiation of calculation model failed; exception 306108
In HANA, I built the calculation view, where it is the external view from the HANA DSO. In the DSO, the data preview is fine and does not throw error, but the same data preview done on Calculation view throws this error:

I tried deleting all the input parameters and also expression in filters, only - in("column_name" ='DSO_name$C') in aggregation before join  and "LANGU" = 'E' is there in default text projection.
I also tried to data preview in aggregation before join node (which is the first node ~staging node), but still the same error is thrown.
Can anyone help or suggest how to resolve this issue?
PS: I also tried this note, but it doesn't help
https://userapps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/3440854
